# Cancel Pending api calls on unmount of react component using react query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I want to cancel pending calls on unmount of a component. I'm using react query **3.39.2**. There are **n** api calls, and the query key is **dynamic**. I've shared the current code below, and it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

PS: It does go inside the if block.

```
const queryClinet = useQueryClient();
useEffect(() => {
return () => {
  queryClient.getQueryCache()
  .getAll()
  .forEach(query => {
    if(query.queryKey.includes('partOfMyKey'))
      queryClient.cancelQueries(query.queryKey);
      // queryClient.cancelQueries({ queryKey: query.queryKey });
  })
}
}, [window.location.href])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query Cancellation alone doesn't do much per default: It cancels the Query itself (so data is not stored), but it doesn't abort the request.

To achieve that, you need to forward the `AbortSignal` provided by react-query to your fetch function. How you do this depends on what you use for data fetching - [the docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/query-cancellation) have multiple examples, but here is the one for `fetch`:

```
const query = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['todos'],
  queryFn: async ({ signal }) => {
    const todosResponse = await fetch('/todos', { signal })
    return todoResponse.json()
  }
})
```

If the `signal` is passed to `fetch`, the Query will be cancelled automatically when the fetch is aborted. This will happen as soon as no component is mounted that is actively using the Query.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there and missing a curly braces {} in your *if* statement.The code should be this :

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient();

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    queryClient.getQueryCache().getAll().forEach(query => {
      if (query.queryKey.includes('partOfMyKey')) {
        queryClient.cancelQueries(query.queryKey);
      }
    });
  };
}, [window.location.href]);
```

Comment: We don't need curly braces if there's only one statement. Besides, it doesn't work with braces as well, as I've mentioned in the question, it does go inside the if block

Comment: @SoumyaSagnikKhanda you r right .In JS if statement with one line code runs well  However, in your specific case, you are using a forEach loop, which contains multiple lines of code inside it. When you want to execute multiple statements as part of the conditional block of an if statement or a loop, you need to use curly braces {} to create a code block for the conditional logic.